# Android : Battery Consumption During Idle TCP connection

Tags: android, tcp, power-management

I am trying to implement a push notification system for my android application. Being logged into a Google account is not allowed as per the SRS. That being the case, C2DM is not possible.

My goal is to use an always on TCP connection that sends a message indicating connectivity periodically so that the server knows it is on.

My problem is battery consumption. I have not implemented this yet, but before I do I need an understanding of how an open TCP connection that is idle affects the battery.

Some guidance on this or where to look would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [this](http://devtcg.blogspot.de/2009/01/push-services-implementing-persistent.html) might be helpful...

Comment: thanks! I saw this article before, but never read the comments.